# Spring State Machine task execution not firing

Tags: spring, asynchronous, spring-statemachine

I am having issues with getting a runnable to run in the manner described in the following reference:

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-statemachine/1.0.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#statemachine-examples-tasks

```
TasksHandler handler = TasksHandler.builder()
    .task("1", sleepRunnable())
    .task("2", sleepRunnable())
    .task("3", sleepRunnable())
    .build();
handler.runTasks();
```

My implementation looks like this:

```
private Action<States, Events> getUnlockedAction() {
    return new Action() {
        @Override
        public void execute(StateContext sc) {
            System.out.println("in action..");
            handler = new TasksHandler.Builder().taskExecutor(taskExecutor()).task("1", dp.runProcess(1)).build();
            handler.addTasksListener(new MyTasksListener());

            handler.runTasks();

            System.out.println("after action..");
        }

    };
}
```

The initialization for the TaskExecutor looks like this:

```
    @Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor te = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    te.setMaxPoolSize(50);
    te.setThreadNamePrefix("LULExecutor-");
    te.setCorePoolSize(25);
    te.initialize();
    return te;
}
```

My code for dp (DataProcessor) looks like this:

```
@Component
@Qualifier("dataProcessor")
public class ADataProcessor {

    public Runnable runProcess(final int i) {
    return new Runnable() {
        @Async
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long delay = (long) ((Math.random() * 10) + 1) * 1000;
            System.out.println("In thread " + i + "... sleep for " + delay);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FSMFactoryConfig.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println("After thread " + i + "...");
        }

    };
    }
}
```

When i execute my code, I see the messages for 'in action..' and 'after action..' with no delay..

When I use the following:

```
                taskExecutor().execute(dp.runProcess(1));
            taskExecutor().execute(dp.runProcess(2));
            taskExecutor().execute(dp.runProcess(3));
            taskExecutor().execute(dp.runProcess(4));
            taskExecutor().execute(dp.runProcess(5));
            taskExecutor().execute(dp.runProcess(6));
```

I get what I would expect from using the TasksHandler..

- state changed to UNLOCKED
- In thread 2... sleep for 10000
- In thread 3... sleep for 5000
- In thread 4... sleep for 8000
- In thread 5... sleep for 4000
- In thread 6... sleep for 4000
- In thread 1... sleep for 9000
- Jan 13, 2016 12:32:13 PM - org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor initialize
- INFO: Initializing ExecutorService
- state changed to LOCKED
- After thread 5...
- After thread 6...
- After thread 3...
- After thread 4...
- After thread 1...
- After thread 2...

None of the messages before or after the delay in the sleep are displayed when using the TasksHandler.  So my question, how do I actually execute my runnable??  If I'm doing it correctly, what should I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've slightly misunderstood few things. First you're linking to `tasks` sample having the original idea which were turned into a [tasks recipe](http://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#statemachine-recipes-tasks). It's also worth to look [unit tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/master/spring-statemachine-recipes/src/test/java/org/springframework/statemachine/recipes/TasksHandlerTests.java) for tasks.

You register runnables with `taskhandler` get a state machine from it to start it and then tell handler to run tasks.

I now realize that in docs I probably should be bit more clear of its usage.

Comment: Ah, I'll take a look..  Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

After adding all tasks to the handler, I had to start the state machine before invoking `runTasks()`.

```java
handler.getStateMachine().startReactively().block();
handler.runTasks();
```